# Any other norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

all norms I've seen on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are either the sup norm or the $l_p$ norms. Are these the only norms that exist or are there others?

Comment: $\|x\| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |x_1+x_2t+x_3 t^2+\cdots+ x_n t^{n-1}|$.

Comment: @copper.hat Is there a name for that norm?

Comment: Consider a trivial norm ($0$ if $\mathbf 0$, $1$ otherwise)

Comment: any symmetric convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defines a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for which that convex body is the unit ball, and every norm arises this way, see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737828/what-polytopes-can-be-induced-by-a-norm/1737966#1737966).

Comment: I call it Fido.

Comment: Just kidding, I don't think it has a well known name.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that's not absolutely homogeneous though. Cause $\|ax\|=|a|\|x\|$ and if x is non zero we would have $\|ax\|=1$ but also $\|ax\|=|a|$

Comment: @user125932 thank you so much

Comment: Thanks, @aldodecristo, I was wondering about that

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Actually I did some research and it can be a norm as long as $mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the trivial valuation (the generalization of absolute value)

Comment: There are infinitely many norms but they all generate the same topology.